# npm script onchange unable to process the scripts while file changes

Tags: javascript, npm, onchange, npm-scripts

I am using npm script `onchange` but this is not working at all. I have installed `7.1.0` this is my folder structure
[Folder Structure can be seen from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLpeR.png)

and the scripts and dependencies that I am using are as follows

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run watch:css",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/scss-styles.scss",
    "watch:css": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "npm-watch": "^0.11.0",
    "onchange": "^7.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "parallelshell": "^3.0.2"
  }
```

when I run `npm start` it stuck and blinks the cursor then I change the file then there is no script being run.

I am unable to solve this problem. Help me out.

Comment: There is a `scss-styles.css` in the folder `css`. It seems like your script is workings as expected. Your configuration works for me. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I guess you could also use a different one like `chokidar-cli` :x